# PHP SOAP how to create nested requests

Tags: php, soap, request, soap-client, complextype

I'm really out of ideas with PHP SOAP client. Main reason for this is probably that I don't fully understand how SOAP and more so how PHP Soap-client works.

I need to get nested elements (I hope that's the right term) from Soap client.

Here is the example I try to create

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:hor="http://Horizon.ExternalServices" xmlns:hor1="http://Horizon.ExternalServices.AFS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SomeFunction>
         <tem:foobar>
            <hor:Foo>lorem</hor:Foo>
            <hor:Bar>ipsum</hor:Bar>
         </tem:foobar>
         <tem:bazbar>
            <hor1:Foo>lorem</hor1:Foo>
            <hor1:Bar>ipsum</hor1:Bar>
            <!--Optional:-->
         </tem:bazbar>
      </tem:SomeFunction>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My first attempt was just to put entire structure as assosiated array (that has always worked before), but with these nested thingis it seems to be a no go.

Then I tried several different methods to create the following structure with SoapVar and SoapParam but because I really don't seem to understand how they work most of the time I'm getting just the request without anything inside the body.

I've read the documention on PHP, wikipedia and w3schools. I just don't seem to get a grasp on the concept.

I'd really appriciate if some one could give me link or anything that explains how the Soap-client actually works.  Also code examples would be much appriciated.

Comment: This normally just works. Post your code, so it can become clear what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same problem and then started to use nusoap class as it is easier  to pass the data in the associative array format and the class builds the xml based on it. You can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

Comment: I'm aware of the nuSOAP lib. Unfortunatellu using external libs (at least the ones that have stopped their developement) is not an option right now. But thanks for the tip.